# How to activate the auto hide folder margin style in notepad ++?

Tags: notepad++

I need help. How do I activate the auto hide folder margin style in notepad ++?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw7oD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to `None` in `Settings > Preferences > Editing > Folder Margin Styles`.